# Integral help with completing the square!!

Tags: calculus, integration

Could you please help me integrate
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2+x-x^2}}$$

I am supposed to complete the square.. but I am seriously stuck. I have tried to square each side and stuff, but it does not seem to be working

Comment: I have updated your post with mathematical formatting, using MathJax.  Take a look at it by hitting the "edit" button; it isn't terribly hard to learn, but makes it much easier to read!

Comment: first factor out a negative. Then the headcoefficient is positive. Now can you complete the square? Once you are done, distribute the negative.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson you've got a telepathy talent!

Comment: $\large 2 + x - x^{2}
=
\left(1 + x\right)\left(2 - x\right).\quad$
$\displaystyle{\large 2 + x - x^{2}
=
-\left(x - {1 \over 2}\right)^{2} + {9 \over 4}}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Completing the square means rewriting a general quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ in the form $a(x-h)^2+k$.  If you want to write $2+x-x^2$ in this form, the first step is to write
$$
2+x-x^2=2-(x^2-x).
$$
Now, if you were going to write $x^2-x=(x-h)^2+z$, what would you need to choose for $h$?  What would this make $z$?

**Hint #2 (Update):**

So, you've found that $2+x-x^2=-(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{9}{4}$, making your integral
$$
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}-(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}}.
$$

Remember that 
$$
\int\frac{dw}{\sqrt{1-w^2}}=\arcsin(w)+C.
$$
Can you see any way to bridge the divide between these two integrals?

Comment: I got till that part. In fact after substitutions and everything, I ended up with (x-.5)^2 = 9/4 and i have u^2 - 9/4. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: @user96740 Updated with a further hint.