# Integrating by completing the square

Tags: calculus, integration

I just had this question on the test and I'm having trouble reflecting if I got it right or wrong.

> $$\int\frac{1}{(-4x-x^2)^\frac12}dx$$

I did $1/(-x)(4 (-x^2))$ as the square but it just didn't seem right.

My answer was $\sin^-1 ((2-x)/x)$.

What was the correct way to complete the square?

Comment: Look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/504280/389416

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to complete the square is to write 
$$
-4x-x^2 = 4-(x+2)^2
$$
So letting $y=x+2$ we have 
$$
\int_{x=a}^{x=b} \frac1{\sqrt{4-(x+2)^2}}dx = \int_{y=a+2}^{y=b+2} \frac1{\sqrt{4-y^2}}dx 
$$
which can then be put into arcsin form by the transformation $z=\frac{y}{2}$.

Comment: So that's how it works! I got it wrong. So the final answer is just arcsin((x+2)/2)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to complete the square was 4 - $(x+2)^2$

There are many ways to do this, one of them being assuming the completed square to be $a(x-\alpha)^2+ \beta$
and then solving for a, $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

After doing this step, solving the integral is quite easy.

Comment: Thanks user! I can't believe I missed this one but it makes sense now after missing it to be able to reflect on it.